# Android tabhost - update views

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have an Android tabhost with 5 tabs, each of which will be updated in the onTabChanged method. However when I open the activity, the first tab just shows a blank screen. If I click on another tab and then come back to the first tab, it will display properly.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you post your code..?

Comment: try this http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/.

Comment: Do you want to update the tab or showing blank screen on first tab? Your question is vague.

Comment: i want to update tab

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Assume that you have used the PagerAdapter to fill the tabs. Can you use the SatePagerAdapter, it will solve the problem. Else please put your code here.

Comment: Maybe after adding the tabs set the first tab as default tab using setCurrentTab().

Comment: show us some code to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to update Tabs after ViewPager taking blank fragments, Using state adapter i solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

maintain a persisting boolean value say isFirstVisit in activity which is by default true.
Inside, ontabchanged if the tabid is anything other than the first tab then change the value of isFirstVisit to false.

When the first tab is opened check if it is first visit using isFirstVisit value and make the tab blank accordingly.

Don`t forget to make the isFirstVisit to true in activity`s onDestroy method